# How can I shutdown another computer with a shutdown script on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, remote-shutdown

okay so I own a pc and a laptop, I (remotely through SSH) use the laptop for some random tasks, but the laptop is somewhat far away from my desk so when I shutdown my pc I have to go walk to my laptop and shut it down as well, I want a way to shutdown my main pc and it will automatically shutdown the other one with it.

so far I've tried a shutdown script that was supposed to remote into my laptop and shut it down as my computer is powering off.

both computer running windows 10 20H2.

Comment: If both are on the same network, you can use the shutdown command to send the shutdown signal directly to that computer. The command is `shutdown /m computername /s`

Comment: So to clarify, you want this automated, correct? You could issue a shutdown command via the SSH connection manually before shutting down the local machine (`shutdown /s`). But if you want it automated then maybe a local group policy shutdown script? Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown

Comment: Try using PSExec (SysInternals) to run your script.